# In-app purchase Restoration process iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

If there is any difference if I don't use **paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished** method but use Restored transaction state in **paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])** like here:

## 1

```
paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("add paymnet")
        
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            
            switch trans.transactionState {
                
            case .Purchased. Restored:
...

and 

...
    @IBAction func RestorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
```

or I will use **paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished** method but in .Restored state in **paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])** I will use just brake operator like here:

## 2

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
//restored code here
}

//and 

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("add paymnet")
        
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            
            switch trans.transactionState {
                
            case .Purchased:
...
            case .Restored:
             break
...

//and 

...
    @IBAction func RestorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**PS**

Should be any difference in code for consumable and non-consumable purchases in restoration process?

Comment: consumable products aren't restorable.

Comment: You need to call `finishTransaction` whether it is a new transaction or a restoration. Basically treat a restoration just like an initial purchase.

Comment: @Paulw11 if you talk about #1, so there I use finishTransaction, but in the #2 I'm not sure about it because I use paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished, but should I?

Comment: I must say I don't really understand what you are asking. It doesn't matter what functions you call in your app. What matters is that you call the right functions in the payment queue and transactions.

Comment: Actually question is "Should I use method paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished" to restore transactions or I can make it in other way like in #1. Sorry for foggy explanation

Comment: You can do it any way you like.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is strange but works only 2 variant...

Comment: figured out! Thank you!